# Google Sheet - How to calculate subtotal including future insertions

Tags: google-sheets

How to calculate the total of a `row` ? as well whenever requried I will keep add more rows in the sheet. according to sheet's row insertion i require to update the total as well.

at present I use this formula : `=SUM(B1:$20)` - But not works.

see the screen shot, the `100` inserted later but the total not updated.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

With your existing setup, use

```
=sum(B$1:B23)
```

then as new rows are added above the Totals row, it will change to

```
=sum(B$1:B24) etc.
```

Comment: very simple, exactly what i expected

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(B:B)
```

Can be used to sum a complete column.  Unfortunately, you would have to move other things out of the way.

Using menu "Data", you can select a range to be named, and then re-define the range, as items get added.